# C++ Parenthesis Operator Overloading Error

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am getting an unexpected error trying to implement ()-overloading according to the following get_chessman() method in a chessboard class: "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have pointer to function type". Am I overloading in the wrong way?

Minimal example code:

In chessboard header:

```
class Chessboard
{
private:
  Chessman** board;
  int size;
  bool turn; // 1 for white, 0 for black
public:
  Chessboard(int size = 8);
  ~Chessboard();
  bool is_whites_turn() const;
  bool is_game_over() const;
  int get_size() const { return size; }
  Chessman* operator() (int row, int col) const; // <------ overloading
  Chessman* get_chessman(int row, int col) const; // reference method
}
```

Implementation:

```
Chessman* Chessboard::operator()(int row, int col) const
{
  return &board[row][col];
}

Chessman* Chessboard::get_chessman(int row, int col) const
{
  return &board[row][col];
}
```

Result:

```
int main() {
  cout << "hello Chess" << endl;
  //Chessboard cb();
  Chessboard* cb = new Chessboard();
  cb->show();
  Chessman* cm = cb->get_chessman(7,4);
  cout << cm->get_symbol() << endl;
  Chessman* cm1 = cb(7, 4); // ERROR: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (point-to-) function
  cout << cm1->get_symbol() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should include the complete verbatim error message in the quesiton.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using so many pointers? Why is `cb` a pointer at all`?

Comment: I am learning :) Thanks for the hint, so I get a reference by doing Chessboard(cb) instead of Chessboard* cb = new Chessboard();, right? That makes my call possible the way I wanted to, simply cb(index1, index2). Alternatively, if I use the pointer, Nelfeal's answer works great.

Comment: @marie_antoinette You don't need a pointer (nor a reference), what you need is an instance to work on. As written, your code leaks memory. In your case, it would be way better to rely on automatic storage since your dynamic allocation of `cb` is unnecessary. Declare it as: `Chessboard cb;` (no parentheses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you dereference `cb` in `cb->get_chessman(7,4)`, you must dereference it in the line in question, like `(*cb)(7, 4)`.

Side note: the way you code is reminiscent of Java where everything is a pointer. You should probably make use of simple variables, references, and standard containers (among other things) when coding in C++. Example:

```
class Chessboard
{
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<Chessman>> board;
  int size;
  bool turn; // 1 for white, 0 for black
public:
  Chessboard(int size = 8);
  ~Chessboard();
  bool is_whites_turn() const;
  bool is_game_over() const;
  int get_size() const { return size; }
  Chessman const& operator() (int row, int col) const; // <------ overloading
  Chessman const& get_chessman(int row, int col) const; // reference method
  void show();
};

Chessman const& Chessboard::operator()(int row, int col) const
{
  return board[row][col];
}

Chessman const& Chessboard::get_chessman(int row, int col) const
{
  return board[row][col];
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello Chess" << std::endl;
  Chessboard cb;
  cb.show();
  auto cm = cb.get_chessman(7,4);
  std::cout << cm.get_symbol() << std::endl;
  auto cm1 = cb(7, 4);
  std::cout << cm1.get_symbol() << std::endl;
}
```